# Sidekiq Forbidden error with Redis sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, sidekiq

Seeing a Forbidden error when we attempt to retry / delete / etc from the sidekiq UI.

Read through a lot of the web traffic on people who experienced this issue, including: https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1289

Running on

- rails 4.1.11
- ruby 2.2.3
- sidekiq-pro 3.0.1
- redis 2.8.21
- puma
- Heroku
- redis-rails for storing sessions

relevant snippets from our app: https://gist.github.com/toddmetheny/4b511e364a4c91ad8187

We're using redis to store sessions. It seemed like a fair number of people having the problem were doing that but there were various problems sharing sessions w/ the sidekiq UI.

Tried most of the things I've seen suggested in the related closed issues without any luck. As described by others, it works well in development...and staging (which seems really weird). Was hoping someone might have something to add. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the comments just posted here:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2487#issuecomment-179667037

Run `bundle update sinatra` to make sure you have the latest Sinatra and Rack stuff.

To properly share the session between Sinatra and Rails, you need to do something like this:

```
Sidekiq::Web.set :session_secret, Rails.application.secrets[:secret_token]
Sidekiq::Web.set :sessions, Rails.application.config.session_options
```

Comment: Thanks. Was missing the sessions_options.